# Number Theory problem I am stuck on

Tags: number-theory

Problem: Bread randomly chooses $6$ positive integers $a, b, c, d, e, f.$ If the probability that $2^a+2^b+2^c+2^d+2^e+2^f$ is divisible by $5$ can be written as $m/n,$ where $m$ and $n$ are positive relatively prime integers, find $m+n.$

So for this problem I just got all the power of $2$ residues modulo $5,$ and I got them as $1, 2, 3, 4.$ Now I am stuck since I don't want to casework bash since that would be very nasty, does anyone have hints or solutions?

Comment: Do it recursively.  You are uniformly choosing $n$ numbers from $\{1,2,3,4\}$...if the sum of the first $n-1$ is not divisible by $5$, then there is a unique choice of the $n^{th}$ which makes the full sum divisible by $5$.

Comment: @lulu, thanks for the hint, but now I am stuck on how to consider the case that the sum of the first $5$ is $0 \pmod{5}.$

Comment: That's why you should work recursively.  Let $p_n$ be the probability that the sum of the first $n$ terms is $0\pmod 5$.  Get a recursion for the $p_n$.

Comment: (Ignoring the fact that there is no uniform probability distribution on a countably infinite set) Alternatively, you want to calculate the sum of coefficients of terms in $ f(x) =  ( x^1+x^2+x^3+x^4)^6$ in which the powers are multiples of 5, which can be obtained via $ \sum f(\omega^i) /5 = 820$ where $ \omega$ is a fifth root of unity, and the probability is $820/4^6$.

Comment: I'm stuck on motive. Why does this bread randomly choose numbers? Most bread, in my experience, just sits there.

Comment: There is no canonical way to randomly “pick a positive integer.”

Answer (score 0):

To flesh out the hint in the comments:

First of all, I am rewriting the question to assume that $B$ is choosing from $\{1,2,3,4\}$ uniformly at random and independently.  This avoids the problem that there is no uniform distribution on the integers (so "randomly choosing" a positive integer does not makes sense).

Then, let $p_n$ be the desired answer for $n$ choices.  That is, $p_n$ is the probability that the sum of the first $n$ choices is $0\pmod 5$.  Of course, it follows that $1-p_n$ is the probability that the sum of the first $n$ choices is *not* divisible by $5$.

Clearly $p_1=0$.  To work recursively, we remark that, in order for the $n^{th}$ sum to be $0\pmod 5$, we need, first, that the $(n-1)^{st}$ sum is not $0\pmod 5$ and then we need to have chosen the unique $n^{th}$ number which makes the $n^{th}$ sum $0\pmod 5$.  Thus $$p_n=(1-p_{n-1})\times \frac 14$$

This can easily be computed by hand out to six terms.  It is not difficult to solve it explicitly, and we get $$p_n=\frac {4^{n-1}-(-1)^{n-1}}{5\times 4^{n-1}}$$

Note that this expression will not generally be in reduced form.  Indeed, $5$ divides the numerator.

Should add:  I feel sure that this is a duplicate of an older problem, but a quick search failed to find the duplicate.